# Equation for this graph

Tags: graphing-functions, plane-curves

I am trying to find an equation for the graph that crosses the Y axis at (0,100), X axis at (100, 0), is a curve with adjustable degree of "bending" and has an axis of symmetry y(x) = x. 
Here are few examples of such graphs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried quadratic, cubic, quartic equations but  I can't adjust the degree at which the curve is bent.  Any hints/tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know a function like the second one. Have a look at it to find if it works or not. That is $$x^{\frac{2}3}+y^{\frac{2}3}=100^{\frac{2}3}$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I played a bit with this one but any type of change involves displacing the crossing points with the axises.

Comment: Salam my friend, have a nice time +)

Comment: @astralmaster One thing that doesn't change crossing points is to replace all three exponents, $2/3$ in the above example, by any number $c$ with $0<c<1$, i.e. $x^c+y^c=100^c$, which meets the axes at $(100,0)$ and $(0,100)$ and has different degrees of bending. As $c$ is taken closer to $0$ the bending increases.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. When I see my friends on the site, I feel good. :)

Comment: Me too, Babak! $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @coffeemath Indeed! Thanks for noticing! That's pretty much what I needed.